# What are the usual RUs values you expect when you run simple queries?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, request-unit

I started a short time ago to experiment with gremlin and cosmos DB, with the idea of doing a prototype for a project at work.

How do I know if a "Request charge value" is good or bad?

For example, I have a query to get a list of flats located in a specific state which looks like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Flat').as('Flats').outE('has_property')
  .inV().has('propertyType',eq('reference')).has('propertyName','City').outE('property_refers_to')
  .inV().hasLabel('City').outE('has_property')
  .inV().has('propertyType',eq('reference')).has('propertyName','State').outE('property_refers_to')
  .inV().hasLabel('State').outE('has_property')
  .inV().has('propertyType',eq('scalar')).has('name',eq('Some_State_Name'))
  .values('name')
  .select('Flats')
```

Each object-property is not stored directly in the node representing an "object" but has its own node. Some properties are "scalar" (like the name of a state or a city) and some are a reference to another node (like the city where a flat is located).

With this query, azure shows me a "Request charge" value of 73.179
Is it good?

What are the things I should try to improve?